# Understanding Base Pointer and Stack Pointers: In Context with gcc Output

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

I have the following C program:

```
int main()
{
    int c[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2};
    return c[0];
}
```

and when compiled using the -S directive with gcc I get the following assembly:

```
    .file   "array.c"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, -48(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -44(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -40(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -36(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $2, -12(%rbp)
    movl    -48(%rbp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

What I do not understand is why are the earlier array elements further from the bp? It almost seems like the elements on the array are being placed in opposite order.

Also why does gcc not use push instead of movl, to push the array elements onto the stack?

---

**DIFFERENT VIEW**

Moving the array to global namespace as a static variable to the module I get:

```
    .file   "array.c"
    .data
    .align 32
    .type   c, @object
    .size   c, 40
c:
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    c(%rip), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Using the following C program:

```
static int c[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2};

int main() 
{
    return c[0];
}
```

This doesn't give more insight to the stack. But it is intersting to see the differement output of assembly using slightly different semantics.

Comment: That is code generated with the gcc command, often times the compiler generates different code that does the same thing. Basically, there are multiple solutions to a problem. Did you optimize with -o when compiling? It could be because of that (or lack of).

Comment: This is actually code generated by the compiler, and it cannot be different from the code generated by the compiler. Optimization flag is `-O` and not `-o`, and yes Matthew used `-Os` as he clearly stated in his question..

Comment: He said `-S` (generate assembly as text), not `-Os` (optimize for size).  This assembly appears to have been generated *without* optimization; at any level of `-O` I see the array stores vanish entirely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the x86 stack grows downwards. By convention, `rbp` stores the original value of `rsp`. Therefore, the function's arguments reside at *positive* offsets relative to `rbp`, and its automatic variables reside at *negative* offsets. The first element of an automatic array has a lower address than all other elements, and thus is the furthest away from `rbp`.

Here is a handy diagram that appears [on this page](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html):

[image: stack layout]

I see no reason why the compiler *couldn't* use a series of `push` instructions to initialize your array. Whether this would be a good idea, I am not sure.

Comment: This diagram would normally be flipped upside down no? Since high memory can be thought of as being at the top of the chip?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan: Perhaps. In terms of clarity, I personally don't have a strong preference either way.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan Maps of a region of memory are invariably drawn with higher addresses toward the top of the page.  Diagrams of data structures, network packets, and the like, however, are often drawn with larger offsets toward the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Zack: A long time ago, I read that little-endian ordering favours graphical diagrams as the above, while big-endian would favor left-to-right top-to-bottom representations.

Comment: @ninjalj IME endianness sometimes affects whether people draw high *bits* within a word on the left or the right, but I have never seen it change whether high addresses are on top or on the bottom.

Comment: @Zack: the idea is that if you have e.g: a DWORD split in two parts in a WORD-sized diagram, the contents read OK.

Answer (score 3):

> *Also why does gcc not use push instead of movl, to push the array elements onto the stack?*

It is quite rare to have a large initialized array in exactly the right place in the stack frame that you *could* use a sequence of pushes, so gcc has not been taught to do that.  (In more detail: array initialization is handled as a block memory copy, which is emitted as either a sequence of move instructions or a call to `memcpy`, depending on how big it would be.  The code that decides what to emit doesn't know where in memory the block is going, so it doesn't know if it could use `push` instead.)

Also, `movl` is faster.  Specifically, `push` does an implicit read-modify-write of `%esp`, and therefore a sequence of `push`es must execute in order.  `movl` to independent addresses, by contrast, can execute in parallel.  So by using a sequence of `movl`s rather than `push`es, gcc offers the CPU more instruction-level parallelism to take advantage of.

Note that if I compile your code with any level of optimization activated, the array vanishes altogether!  Here's `-O1` (this is the result of running `objdump -dr` on an object file, rather than `-S` output, so you can see the actual machine code)

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

and `-Os`:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2:   c3                      retq
```

Doing nothing is always faster than doing something.  Clearing a register with `xor` is two bytes instead of five, but has a formal data dependence on the old contents of the register and modifies the condition codes, so *might* be slower and is thus only chosen when optimizing for size.

Comment: mmm, I would expect xor'ing a register with itself to be special-cased, but yeah, it _might_ be slower.

Comment: I don't have any x86 optimization guides to hand, but my recollection is that some models do special case that operation and some don't.  If you don't tell it otherwise, GCC tries to generate code that is reasonably well tuned on a wide range of CPUs, although not perfectly tuned for any specific one.

Comment: I would suppose that it is not taught to do so *because* it would be slower. It would be quite easy to make a difference here, but as it would be inefficient, it is not done.

Comment: `push` isn't slower anymore; Intel since Pentium-M (and AMD since a similar time) [have a "stack engine" that breaks the dependency chain through RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture) and make push/pop single-uop instructions.   It would be a win over mov-zero ([What C/C++ compiler can use push pop instructions for creating local variables, instead of just increasing esp once?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49485395)), also for code size (push imm8 vs. REX movq imm32), but pxor-zero / movdqa 16-byte stores are even better here.

Comment: `xor`-zeroing has been special-cased since before(?) PPro ([What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33666617)), although it actually did still have a false dependency up through PIII.  The reason you don't get xor-zeroing with `-O1` is that `-fpeephole2` is only enabled at `-O2` and higher.  `-O1` is partial optimization; `-Os` is full optimization for size (and speed); `-O3` is full optimization for speed.  (I'm sure you figured out most of these things in the 10 years since you posted, but this answer has some misinformation :/)

Comment: Also `push` would push two array elements per instruction, vs. GCC's unoptimized asm naively storing 4 bytes at a time.  Modern GCC -O0 at least uses `movq`, while `-O3` uses 2x `movaps` + `movq`-immediate.  (If you pass the array to a caller so the zeroing can't optimize away).  https://godbolt.org/z/nfs9sfsj6

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that on x86 the stack grows downward. Pushing onto the stack will subtract from the stack pointer.

```
%rbp <-- Highest memory address
-12
-16
-20
-24
-28
-32
-36
-40
-44
-48  <-- Address of array
```

Comment: Draw a chart like this every time you are confused and you will stop being confused pretty quickly!