# Direct assembly code execution in VBA part 2; 64 bit

Tags: assembly, com, x86-64, 64-bit, calling-convention

I have a COM method; it is supplied with a `this` pointer and returns a `hresult`. I want to display a message box. This is my 32 bit version

```
push 0              ; MB_OK
push DWORD PTR [captionAddress]   ; Address of 'Hello World' caption
push DWORD PTR [textAddress]      ; Address of 'Hello World' text
push 0              ; hWnd
call DWORD PTR [MessageBoxWAddress] ; Direct call to MessageBoxW
xor eax, eax        ; Clear EAX register, essentially setting HRESULT to S_OK (0)
ret 4               ; Return, and adjust stack by 4 bytes (for the "this" pointer)
```

works

This is my 64 bit version

```
mov r9d, 0                   ; Set uType = MB_OK for MessageBoxW
mov rdx, <textAddress>       ; Set lpText pointer for MessageBoxW
mov r8, <captionAddress>     ; Set lpCaption pointer for MessageBoxW
xor rcx, rcx                 ; Set hWnd = NULL for MessageBoxW
mov rax, <MessageBoxWAddress>; Load address of MessageBoxW into RAX
call rax                     ; Call MessageBoxW function
xor rax, rax                 ; Clear RAX to return HRESULT = S_OK
ret                          ; Return
```

Does not work. It gets an access violation. Am I understanding 64 bit calling correctly?

`<MessageBoxWAddress>` is a literal from winapi `GetProcAddress` for MessageBoxW

related:

[Hello World direct Assembly Code execution in VBA - so close but Access Violation on Return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77186271/6609896)

Comment: You also need to allocate shadow space and align the stack pointer. Insert `sub rsp, 40` at the start and of course restore it before returning.